styles from CSS and images not loaded but GET requests shows 200
I have some questions about why none of the CSS styles was used as well as images not being displayed when I call my html from localhost in FireFox.
I have my html code like this:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- <base href="index.html"> -->
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./myCustomStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Document's Special Title here!lala</title>
    
    
</head>
<body>
    This is HTML here!
    

    <p class="hometown">
        Another line here!
    </p>

    <img src="check.png" alt="an image here" width="100" height="88">

    <p id="para1">
        Should be in Yellow color this line.
        Document.get
    </p>

    <p>
        <a href="https://www.Youtube.com/">
            <img src="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assets/questions/media/426142-1668760872.png" alt="not shown!" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </a>
    </p>

    <h1 style ="color:blue"> A simple Chat Application</h1>
    <h2> a h2 here </h2>
    <p> a new paragraph!</p>
    <p> current module: __dirname</p>
</body>
</html>

and my CSS code here:
p.hometown {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: green;
}

h4 {
    background-color:blue;
}

h1 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#para1{
    color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

#geeks {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: skyblue;
}

they both locate in the same level within the structures (a picture of their relationship is here, the index.html and myCustomStyle.css are at the "same level" in the hierachy):
enter image description here
However, none of the images and styles were displayed when I run in localhost as can be seen here:
enter image description here
does anyone knows why none of my images and styles were loaded when I run my html using localhost?
I have spent hours trying to fix the problem like fixing the link's href attribute by including . or / or ./ and also inspect the web developer tools in FireFox, but so far no success.
Could someone gives me a hand.
thanks a lot
Also I was running the server from Vscode using my code here with the port number being 8080 as can be seen here, but this should be irrelevant to the problem at hand, but I would just post here for reference:
enter image description here
also when I used LiveServer in Vscode, I was able to get the html properly:
enter image description here
but none of the images and styles were loaded when I run localhost:8080 from my FireFox or Chrome or IE browser.
I have tried fixing the href by testing relative or direct link. But none of those works yet. Also liveserver from VsCode was able to show how my html should display when the image and styles were loaded successfully.
Edit: The Response Tab after clicking myCustomStyle.css in Developer Tool

my Visual Studio Code to set up the server:
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 8080
const { replaceStr } = require('./utility.js')
const tooo = require('./tools');

// Create a server object:
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    
 
    var isDone  = false;
    //const filedata = fs.readFile('inputfile2.txt');
    //filedata = fs.readFileSync('inputfile1.txt');
    console.log("right after readfile!!");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write('Error: File not being found!')
        } else {
            console.log("type of p2: " + typeof tooo.p2);
            res.write("Data wrote from Server\n:" + data)
            //res.write(filedata)
            //res.write("I am here!!")
            console.log(typeof tooo.foo);
            console.log(typeof tooo.bar);
            console.log("the third function's type: " + typeof tooo.test1);
            console.log("current module dir:" + __dirname);
            
            
            //res.write("Send to me from server:" + typeof tooo.foo);
            
            //res.write();
        }
        res.end()
    
    })

    
    
    //console.log(filedata.toString());
    //console.log("End of Program execution");


    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})


    // Write a response to the client
    res.write('Hello World')
    //res.write(filedata.toString());
 
    // End the response 
    //res.end()
})
 
// Set up our server so it will listen on the port
server.listen(port, function (error) {
 
    // Checking any error occur while listening on port
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', error);
    }
    // Else sent message of listening
    else {
        console.log('Server is listening on port' + port);
        server.timeout = 100;
        console.log(server.timeout);
    }
})


If you click on the myCustomStyle.css line in the dev-tools Network panel then select the Response tab, can you see the CSS as expected? It's worrying that it says "type: HTML"

^Same for the (non-external) PNG btw

@DarkBee Hi, could you elaborate little more about what you mean when you say "Same for the PNG"? sorry I am new to http and css, so not quite understand your explanations. thanks a lot for the help.

What @Phil was pointing out, check your screenshot of the network tab. The returned type for both your CSS and image are "HTML", this isn't correct. Probably this is a server config issue and the file-handlers aren't set properly.

@Phil Hi Phil, thanks for your response. Indeed when I follow your instructions to look at the Response tab after clicking myCustomSystle.css, I don't see the CSS being applied since the line "Should be in Yellow color this line" didn't turn yellow. I have added a screenshot to Response tab in my question. Could you give me a suggestion how to fix the problem? Also I don't quite understand how to fix the "type:HTML" problem as well that you mentioned. Could you give me more instructions. Thanks a lot.

@DarkBee Hi Bee, may I know how to go about fixing the issues? because yes you are right it seems it is not correct for my check.png to be of type HTML.

So looks like every URL is serving your HTML page. What URL do you open in your browser to access the page (as in what is literally in the location bar)? Are you using a server of some kind and if so, what and how is it configured?

@Phil I used vscode to setup the server, as can be seen above. I have attached my code here now as well.

@Phil no the exact thing that I typed into the address bar is just localhost:8080 . Nothing more nothing less.

So you're running a Node.js HTTP server that only serves index.html for every request. Do you not see the issue there? I'd recommend using something simpler like VSCode's Live Server extension. If you really want a Node.js server, I'd recommend Express with its static middleware
